# while loop not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this code to work. I think it has something to do with the while loop. Also I'm new to JavaScript so, if you any suggestions on ways to improve the syntax or make my code more efficient it would be greatly appreciated.

**how the code should work.**
 The user enters a cost of an item and then the amount of
 money given. The program will figure out the change and the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies needed for the change.

**what happens when run**
the two prompt boxes pop up and than I get a alert warning..

"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue."

https://jsfiddle.net/krighty78/g44ejnbw/1/

```js
    /* The user enters a cost of an item and then the amount of
         money given. The program will figure out the change and the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies needed for the change.*/


    var cost = prompt('please enter total cost of the item without tax');
    cost = parseFloat(cost);

    var moneyGiven = prompt('please enter the amount of money given');
    moneyGiven = parseFloat(moneyGiven);

    var tax = 0.15;
    tax = (cost * tax);

    var quarter = 0;
    var dime = 0;
    var nickel = 0;
    var penny = 0;

    var q = 0.25;
    var d = 0.10;
    var n = 0.05;
    var p = 0.01;
    var change = (moneyGiven - (cost + tax));
    console.log(change);

    while (change > 0) {

      if (change >= q) {
        change - q;
        quarter++;
      } else if (change >= d) {
        change - d;
        dime++;
      } else if (change >= n) {
        change - n;
        nickel++;
      } else if (change >= p) {
        change - p;
        penny++;
      }

    }; //while loop

    console.log(quarter);
    console.log(dime);
    console.log(nickel);
    console.log(penny);
```

Comment: For debugging questions, please post the desired and the actual behaviour.

Comment: You don't assign the new value to `change`, use `change -= q;` or `change = change - q;`

Comment: I think it's missing to change the of 'change' variable. Like the code `change - d`, should not be `change = change - d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop is OK, the problem is in the statements

```
change - q;
change - d;
change - n;
change - p;
```

You are not updating the value of `change`. Change these to:

```
change = change - q;
change = change - d;
change = change - n;
change = change - p;
```

Comment: This worked!, thanks for the help.